# Trouble importing Data.List.\\

Tags: haskell, import, operators

I am trying to write a Haskell module which uses the set difference operator from Data.List, but when I try to import it specifically I get the message `parse error on input ‘\\’` when trying to import my module.

Here's an example module which has the same problem:

```
module SetDiff (
    setDiff
) where

-- import Data.List -- No error when this line is used
import Data.List (\\) -- Causes the parse error

setDiff l1 l2 = l1 \\ l2
```

Importing all of `Data.List` allows me to avoid the issue, but is there a way I can perform an import specifying just the `\\` operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `\\` is an **operator**, that will call, behind the curtains, the corresponding **[`(\\) :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:-92--92-) function**, so you need to import the function name, **including the brackets**:

```
import Data.List ((\\))
```

After all, you import a list of *functions* (and other elements like types, typeclasses, etc.), and the "*name*" of the function is **`(\\)`**, not `\\`.

So between the outer brackets, we list the functions we want to import, and the inner brackets, do not act as "groupers" or some independent syntactical element, only as part of the function name.

For example:

```
Prelude> import Data.List ((\\))
Prelude Data.List> [1, 4, 2, 5] \\ [1, 3, 0, 2]
[4,5]
```

Note that you can declare your `setDiff` function as:

```
setDiff :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
setDiff = (\\)
```

so without the parameters.